# Nash Equilibrium for n-shops Location Game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

So if two ice cream shops were to be placed in the location $[0,1]$, inorder to maximize their own pay offs, they both would finally come to the location $[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$. This is also the Nash Equilibrium of the problem and does not require a lot of mathematics to understand.

Now my problem was when we are playing this game for 3 different shops, like there is no intuitive answer for the problem. Every possible answer I thought of ($[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$, $[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}]$ etc.) is not a Nash Equilibrium.

So like is there a mathematical way that I can use to find the Nash equilibrium location for this game, or prove that it doesn't exist.

Also can this be generalized to $4,5 ...n$ games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following two claims hold in the general $n$-shop case.

**Claim 1.** In equilibrium a shop closest to an edge (0 or 1) cannot be alone.

**Proof.** Such a shop could gain customers by moving slightly inward.

**Claim 2.** In equilibrium at most two shops can be in any location.

**Proof.** Assume there is an equilibrium where there are three or more shops in a location. Denote the number of customers coming to this location from the left and right by $c_l$ and $c_r$ respectively. (In the 3-shop case $c_l + c_r = 1$.) All shops in the location have a payoff of $(c_l + c_r)/n$. By moving slightly to the left, a shop can attain a payoff that is arbitrarily close to $c_l$, and by moving slightly to the right a shop can attain a payoff that is arbitrarily close to $c_r$, therefore it can attain (almost) $\max(c_l;c_r)$. It is easy to show that if $n >2$ then
$$
\frac{c_l + c_r}{n} < \max(c_l;c_r). 
$$

---

Using these two properties it is very easy to show that in the 3-shop case there is no pure Nash-equilibrium, so this is left as an exercise.

I happen to have a [Desmos](https://student.desmos.com/join/pu8zpg) for this, if you'd like you can use it to validate the claims and reason about the proof.

---

Note: a mixed equilibrium does exist, see [Shaked, A. (1982): *Existence and Computation of Mixed Strategy Nash Equilibrium for 3-Firms Location Problem*.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2098006)

---

Interestingly, $n = 3$ is the only case without a pure equilibrium, $n \in \left\{2,4,5\right\}$ all have one, and for other $n$ values there are infinitely many equilibria. For a formal characterization one needs some additional properties, but no advanced mathematics. For a detailed discussion see
[Eaton, B.C., and R.G. Lipsey (1975): *The Principle of Minimum Differentiation Reconsidered: Some New Developments in the Theory of Spatial Competition*.](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/42/1/27/1538204?redirectedFrom=fulltext)